# Display values from php mysql array separately

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

What im trying to do is to save vales of "option" from all records in array to be able to echo them out later. I don't know how to display them seperatly. Feel stuck. Any sugestions?

My code:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT option FROM `myoptions` WHERE id IN (1, 7, 18, 24);");
$row = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_array())  { 
    echo $row[] = $row["option"];
}

echo $option1 = $row[0];
echo $option2 = $row[1]; 
echo $option3 = $row[2];
echo $option4 = $row[3];
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'display them separately'?

Comment: what is the error you facing??

Comment: may be it will help https://3v4l.org/ktGdG

Comment: i want to use my 'option' variables in a different part of the page and my problem is that variables are empty.

Comment: Can you show us the code, where you are trying to use it, and getting the empty variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu should store the value in  an array

```
$cnt = 0;
while($row = $result->fetch_array())  { 

  $for_future_use[$cnt] = $row["option"]; 
  $cnt++; 
}
```

and then use later

```
foreach($for_future_use as $key=>$value) {
   echo $value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
$my_array = array("a" => "Cat","b" => "Dog", "c" => "Horse");
$i = 1;
$option = "option";
foreach($my_array as $val)
{
    ${$option.$i} = $val;
    $i++;
}

echo "\$option1  =>  ".$option1."  \$option2 =>  ".$option2."  \$option3  =>  ".$option3;
```

DEMO : https://3v4l.org/OhQSm

i hope it will be helpful.